# How can I scan other mobile phones using Bluetooth on my react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a project application that scans other mobile phones using bluetooth and make a log of the scanned devices to take attendance in class, I used react-native-ble-plx as well as react-native-ble-manager but my app could only scan other small devices such as headphones and nodes, will using a bluetooth classic library allow me to successfully scan mobile phones?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy can only find devices that are currently visible. You are using BLE and can therefore only find devices that are currently advertising some services. Not every phone does this all the time. To be absolutely sure to find all devices, they would need to install an app that advertises. This is the same approach most of the covid tracking apps use

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan i saw your other comments and you mentioned nRFConnect. is there a way to embed an app like that onto my application or is there any react native library that allows us to advertise phones

Comment: I found [this one](https://github.com/vitorpamplona/react-native-ble-advertiser) with a simple google search

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan i came across this one and working on implementing it thank you so much you helped me alot

Comment: @Yaman Have you completed your project?